# Firestore memory limit exceeded on get multiple documents from collection

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm attempting to get all documents within a Firestore collection where my field `referredBy` is equal to a variable, `refCode` (a referral code). I continue to receive the error in Stackdriver: "Error: memory limit exceeded. Function invocation was interrupted."

Instructions for this feature are here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_multiple_documents_from_a_collection

I have tried increasing the memory allocation for this cloud function to 2 GB (max), but still the same error. There are only two documents in this collection and only one that matches my "where" criteria, so the size of the documents shouldn't be the issue anyway.

This is from my index.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const app = express();

// Get referred users:
app.get('path/to/myapp', (req, res) => {

    var getReferred = require('./getRefUsers');
    if (admin.apps.length === 0 ) { admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase); }
    var db = admin.firestore();
    getReferred.getUsersReferred(req, res, db);
});
exports.getReferred = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

Which calls the below function:

```
module.exports = {

getUsersReferred: function(req, res, db) {

    const { shopName, twitchId } = req.query;

    // Get users account to get their referral code:
    var docRef = db.collection('stores').doc(shopName).collection('users').doc(twitchId);
    docRef.get()
        .then((docSnapshot) => {                                                                    
            if (!docSnapshot.exists) {
                var msg = 'User ' + twitchId + ' does not exist.';
                console.log(msg);
                res.json({ 'status': 'error', 'message': msg });
            } else {

                var referredUsers = [];

                // Get all users who were referred by this user
                var refCode = docSnapshot.data().referralCode;
                console.log('refCode: ' + refCode + ' shop: ' + shopName + ' id: ' + twitchId);

                db.collection('stores').doc(shopName).collection('users').where("referredBy", "==", refCode)
                    .get()
                    .then(function(querySnapshot) {
                            console.log('Size: ' + querySnapshot.size);

                            querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
                                // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
                                console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
                                var username = doc.data().username;
                                var earned = doc.data().earnedreferpoints;
                                var id = doc.data().twitchId;
                                if (typeof earned == 'undefined' || earned == 'no') {
                                    earned = 'No';
                                } else {
                                    earned = 'Yes';
                                }

                                if (doc.data().referredBy == refCode) {
                                    referredUsers[id] = [username, earned];
                                }

                            });

                            // After assembling json object, send to user:
                            res.json({ 'status': 'success', 'data': referredUsers} );
                    })
                    .catch(function(error) {
                        var msg = 'Error getting users you have referred. Please contact us.';
                        console.log(msg + ' ', error);
                        res.json({ 'status': 'error', 'message': msg });
                    });
            }

        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            var msg = '';
            console.log(msg);
            res.json({ 'status': 'error', 'message': msg });
    });

}
};
```

The code never reaches the `.then()` block. `console.log('Size: ' + querySnapshot.size);` is not printed to the Stackdriver log.

Comment: You're only showing a partial function here.  Please edit the question that show the *complete, minimal* code that reproduces the problem, so that we can see the whole picture.

Comment: @DougStevenson I've added all relevant code. That from my index.js and the full function for what I'm trying to do. Thanks for looking!

Comment: How many users do you think match the query?  What if you run the same query in a node process on your desktop?

Comment: That could be a lead https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas
Have you monitored your quotas ?

Comment: @DougStevenson there's only 1 user that matches the query, only 2 users in the entire database as I'm just testing this feature out. I have not tested it out on my desktop yet, I will try that.

Comment: @kevincoulibaly I'm on the Blaze plan, but nonetheless I'm well under the free quota. Less than 100 per day.

Comment: Quota has nothing to do with available memory.  If your database query never finishes, and always terminates due to lack of memory, all evidence suggests that your query is returning more documents than can fit in memory.

Comment: @DougStevenson I have tried this on my local machine, it works as expected. I changed the `res.json` s to `console.log` s. It prints out the data for the 1 entry it found, then prints out the referredUsers array with the 1 element.

Comment: Then it might be some problem with the thing you're passing to res.json().

Comment: @DougStevenson right after I make the call to the DB I have a `console.log('Size: ' + querySnapshot.size);` which is never printed to the log, so it's erroring on the `.get()` to the DB.

Comment: Don't know what to tell you, sorry.  Make sure all your libraries are up to date.  Start with the most simple example and work you way up to something more complicated.  People make Firestore queries all the time, so it is not fundamentally broken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

If anyone knows *why* this works, please let me know.

So my variable `var referredUsers = [];` is created before I make the call to the Firestore database. When my query finds a match, it adds data like this to referredUsers: `referredUsers[id] = [username, earned];` which is treating `referredUsers` like a dictionary/object and not an array. This worked fine running on my local machine, and printed referredUsers as: `[ <274940135 empty items>, [ 'areliven', 'Yes' ] ]` which looks odd and I do not fully understand. But somehow this was causing me to exceed the memory limit when running in a Firebase cloud function.

How I Fixed It

Changed `var referredUsers = [];` to `var referredUsers = {};` that's it! Now locally it prints out `{ '274940135': [ 'areliven', 'Yes' ] }` and it runs fine on Firebase cloud functions.

Again, if anyone could shed some light on how this may have caused me to exceed a memory limit on Firebase, it'd be great to know!

Comment: Like you already found, JavaScript arrays are special types of objects, so you could treat it like a dictionary, even though that is not really its use. In your case, if your dictionary key is `'274940135'` and you would then get the size of the `referredUsers` with `referredUsers.lenght`, you would see the array tells you it has a length of `'274940136'` even though it has 1 item. I think the CF runtime reserves memory space for your dynamic `'274940136'` item array, which is probably over the memory limit.